# Android TextView: Conflict with another tag that has the same ID

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-viewbinding

I have a problem with Android XML files and I need your help. I have the following code:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewA"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="A"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.012"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.671" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewS"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="S"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.012"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.584" />
```

So basically I have two TextViews. When I compile, I get the error message:

```
'<TextView id='@+id/textView'> conflicts with another tag that has the same ID'
```

and when I click at the respective lines of the error, those two TextViews are shown. I do not really understand this because they do not have the same ID. They used to have the same ID but I changed it, still the problem occurs. Maybe this has something to do with ViewBinding that I just enabled? I'd appreciate every comment.

Update: I realized that in fact is has something to do with the ViewBinding because I also can see the following information:

```
Found data binding error(s):

[databinding] {"msg":"\u003cTextView id\u003d\u0027@+id/textView\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\T.D\\AndroidStudioProjects\\BarApp\\BarApp_Projekt\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_cocktail_ytest.xml","pos":[{"line0":48,"col0":4,"line1":61,"col1":52}]}
[databinding] {"msg":"\u003cTextView id\u003d\u0027@+id/textView\u0027\u003e conflicts with another tag that has the same ID","file":"C:\\Users\\T.D\\AndroidStudioProjects\\BarApp\\BarApp_Projekt\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_cocktail_ytest.xml","pos":[{"line0":121,"col0":4,"line1":134,"col1":52}]}
```

But still I do not know the cause of the error. I mean they definetely do not have the same ID.

Comment: can you add your activity_cocktail_ytest xml ?

Comment: Thanks Abdul for your comment. Basically the code from above is from the XML layout file 'activity_cocktail_ytest xml '

Comment: have you tried invalidating the cache ?

Comment: Thanks Abdul for your answer and help. Indeed invalidating the cache helped. Why did I have to do this?

Comment: Hi Abdul. As said before, your introction helped me solve the problem. I would like to know why and when I have to invaildate the cache? I'd appreciate every answer (if you post it as an answer to this question, I will vote your answer up and mark it as the correct answer, such that you get points)

Comment: For data binding android studio auto generate file. Some times file from the cache are used which are not latest. So when you invalidate cache, these file are generated again upon build.

Comment: it depends but normally when you have issue with data binding and you think that everything is good, then invalid cache is a great option.

Comment: Thanks Abdul for your great help :-)

Comment: Is this question about the data binding or View binding. if this is about the Data Binding then please change the tag and remove the view binding tag.

Comment: Thanks Kumar for your answer. No, this question is not about Data Binding but View Binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invalidate caches and restart android studio will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and then Rebuild

Comment: Thanks Reham for your answer. Basically this did not resolve the problem. However, invalidating the cache helped (altough I do not understand why)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68280374/6386888

Delete your project and pull source code from git again.
It may can help